# My Window.xaml in WPF contains only one DataGrid and it's opening really slow.. (performance or data binding issue)

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, datagrid

I am using app where I got one window called MainWindow.xaml and on my window I have `DataGrid` which is used to show some items from database, My DataGrid took 90% place of my MainWindow.Xaml, its simply all over the screen.

And even If I have like 20 items in `DataGrid` I need aproximately **1,60**  (*sometimes 2 seconds, sometimes 1,60 seconds, sometimes 1,45 seconds*) seconds to open that MainWindow.xaml. And I can only imagine what's gonna happen on 200+ items.

I tried a lot of stuffs to increase performance but that did not helped me a lot.

Before I list what I've tried I will write here how I'm binding data (I'm doing it from code behind).

```
List<Product> myList =ProductsController.GetAll();
dtgProducts.ItemsSource = myList;
```

Now I will list what I have tried allready:

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"

EnableRowVirtualization ="True"

EnableColumnVirtualization = "True"

AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

I even set MaxWidth and MaxHigh to some unreal dimensions just to keep it fixed, because I read somehwere that might help:

```
MaxWidth="4000" MaxHeight="2000"
```

And now here is full code :

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" Name="dtgProductsts" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" MaxWidth="4000" MaxHeight="2000"  EnableRowVirtualization ="True" EnableColumnVirtualization = "True" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#d3d3d3" AlternatingRowBackground="#E0E4E5" AlternationCount="2"  GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" FontSize="16" RowHeight="30" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Background="White" Margin="5,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>


                </Style>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                   Color="LightBlue"/>
                </DataGrid.Resources>   
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PRO}"   Header="Product number"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="10*"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalAmount, StringFormat=N2}"    Header="Ukupno"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/> 
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PaymentType}"    Header="Payment($)"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClientName}"      Header="Client Name"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: How long does it take for your ProductsController.GetAll() method to return?

Comment: Also setting the ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll attached property to false will disable virtualization.

Comment: @mm8 ProductsController.GetAll()  method needs like 0.1sec to return all items from database, and to open window with DataGrid I need like, more than 1 sec, and that really means a lot to me..

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` attached property to false will disable the UI virtualization. Don't do this.

You should probably also consider calling the `ProductsController.GetAll()` method on a background thread once the window has been loaded.

You could display a `ProgressBar` during the time it takes for the method to complete, e.g.:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += Window_Loaded;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
        {
            return ProductsController.GetAll();
        }).ContinueWith(task => 
        {
            dtgProducts.ItemsSource = task.Result;
            pb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

---

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" Name="dtgProductsts"
                  MaxWidth="4000" MaxHeight="2000"
                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#d3d3d3" AlternatingRowBackground="#E0E4E5" AlternationCount="2" 
                  GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" FontSize="16" RowHeight="30" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Background="White" Margin="5,0"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PRO}"   Header="Product number"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="10*"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalAmount, StringFormat=N2}"    Header="Ukupno"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PaymentType}"    Header="Payment($)"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClientName}"      Header="Client Name"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pb" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I added breakpoing in  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) method but It's never being hitted.. even if in the constructor I wrote like you said this.Loaded+=...  how come.. ? :)

Comment: Does your window even show up? Are you sure that you added the code to the correct window class? If you put a breakpoint in the constructor, does it get hit?

Comment: Window is showing up, and in constructor next line is being hitted: this.Loaded += Window_Loaded; but private method Window_Loaded wont get executed, I put also breakpoint on begining of Window_Loaded method but it wont execute.. I don't know why :/

Comment: Please provide a repo of your issue if you want anyone to be able to help you out then: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve